# Intermittent "no trusted certificate found" errors

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

For our web application servers we monitor with both Sitescope and Big Brother.  Twice this week both have alerted our Operations team at the sametime.  The Sitescope error is "no trusted certificate found", the BB error is not descriptive, just that connecting to the login page failed. Each time the problem goes away by itself with in 1 to 5 minutes.

There are many hits when searching for the "no trusted certificate found" message but I can not find an other example where the problem is intermittent.  I don't know if it is an application issue, a server configuration problem, or a problem with the monitoring tools.

Comment: I'm seeing intermittent failures like this too, using the Apache HttpClient stack from inside an Android app.